# Given two trees, how do you find one of the tree is a subtree of other?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given two trees, how do you find one of the tree is a subtree of other?
Give the best algorithm for this ... and also give the order of what you have answered ...

Comment: You could do an inorder traversal and then check if the smaller sequence is a contiguous sub-sequence in the longer sequence.

Comment: Does trees are bidirectional ? What is the parameters: tree roots/just a 2 nodes?

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that comes to mind is to traverse one tree, and see if any of it's children is the head of the other tree.  and then reverse.

If you know the height of each of the trees, you can probably figure out which tree is possibly a sub-tree of the other.

If you know other details or characteristics of your trees(sorted or not, balanced or not), you can come up with even faster algorithms, using those characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we can do : Suppose we have a function called `isSubSet` gets the root of two trees. On the other hand we have a function called `isIdentical` which checks whether two trees are identical.

Let's assume we want to see whether tree S is a subset of tree T. If T and S are identical, they are, otherwise we go through S by calling `isSubset` function again. But this time we send T->Left and S for left sub tree of T and T->Right and S for right sub tree of S.

You can find code and more information in [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/13942).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have bidirectional trees you should simply call twice this method, complexity will be O(k), where k=n+m, where n and m - heights of both trees.

```
isSubtree(Node n1, Node n2){
   while(n2.parent != null){
      if(n2.parent == n1){
         return true;
      }
      n2=n2.parent;
   }
   return false;
}
```

You can do even better if you'll remember visited parent nodes:

```
isParent(Node n1, Node n2){
   Set<Node> parents = new HashSet<Node>();
   parents.add(n1);
   parents.add(n2);
   while(n1.parent != null || n1.parent != null){
        if (parents.contains(n1.parent)){
            n1 is subtree of n2
        }
        if (parents.contains(n2.parent)){
            n2 is subtree of n1
        }
       parents.add(n1.parent);
       parents.add(n2.parent);
       n1=n1.parent;
       n2=n2.parent;
   }
   not a subtrees
}
```